# PHP SoapClient does not work with basic authentication

Tags: php, http, soap

I am having trouble with accessing a 3rd party SOAP service using PHP SoapClient.

The service requires basic authentication and despite providing the username and password, I always get an "authorization required" exception.

I've tried many suggestions from other, similar threads, none helped. 
The nusoap library created a massive memory leak and could not cope with the call even with 1 GB of memory allowed for PHP.

Below is the class I put together to test the service.

```
class SoapCallService
{

    private $username = 'xxx';
    private $password = 'yyy';


    public function checkCPRNumber($cprNumber)
    {

        try {
            $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
                )
            );
            $context = stream_context_create($opts);

            $soapClientOptions = array(
                'stream_context' => $context,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'login' => $this->username,
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
                'location' => "http://zzz.zz",
                'trace' => 1
            );


            $client = new SoapClient($this->getWSDL(), $soapClientOptions);
            $request = [
                'PersonInformation' => [
                    "PersonCPRNumber" => $cprNumber,
                ],
                'Kontekst' => [
                ]

            ];

            var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

            $result = $client->__soapCall('CSRPValidation', [$request]);
            print_r($result);

            print "<p>Request :" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . "</p>";
            print "<p>Response:" . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()) . "</p>";

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    private function getWSDL()
    {
        return '/path/to/local/Service.wsdl';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could try ntlm authentication, PHP SoapClient doesn't support it natively (I don't think) but nusoap does. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218466/php-ntlm-authentication-soap-client and http://blog.joaomorais.com/how-to-use-ntlm-authentication-with-nusoap/

Comment: Could probably try to pass the credentials via the context options, by adding an `Authentication` header in there …?